# Detect Live Server Side changes (Long Polling, Short Polling or Web Sockets)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, websocket, long-polling

### Justification and Research

I have a site that requires users to login in order to view. Whilst users are logged in, I would like to keep an eye on their user session. By this, I mean that I would like to know whether or not their user session has expired, and therefore redirect them.

Each user's session lasts 1 hour (or whatever I set it to), and is reset if they visit a different page (like most login systems).

At present, I have the following algorithm:

1. User arrives at private page (javascript method called `isUserAuthorized()` is executed)
2. The `isUserAuthorized()` javascript method makes an AJAX request to the page 'ajax.example.net/authorized'
3. This page returns a JSON object indicating the current status of the user like so:

`{ authorized: true, timeout: 3600000 }`

1. The javascript method then sets a timeout to call the method again in `timeout` milliseconds, assuming that the session will have ended then.
2. If the session has ended then redirect the user, otherwise recall in the method in `timeout` milliseconds.

There are two reasons I do not like this current method:

1. I have had issues with time syncing between client and server clocks, this is weird but it definitely causes an issue...
2. It leaves a timeout in the background of the webpage, and as this site is very javascript heavy, I would rather not have this additional timeout in order to keep the site as smooth as possible.

### My Question

My question is therefore, can anybody think of a better way to achieve this? I have thought of long polling or websockets, but I am not 100% sure how to use either of these and the tutorials on websockets that I found were not very good! Would these actually be a better solution?

I could workaround the time syncing issues but before I do, I want to ensure that there are not better ways to achieve this...

In case it helps, here is my current code:

```
// Set the Authorized Timeout
MN.authorizedTimeout = setTimeout(function(){MN.isUserAuthorized});

/**
 * Is User Authorized
 * Checks to see if the current user is authorized and
 * makes sure their session is still active
 */
MN.isUserAuthorized = isUserAuthorized;
function isUserAuthorized(){
    // TEMPORARY
    console.log('authorising');
    // Set the authorized var
    var authorized = false;
    // Clear the current timeout
    clearTimeout(MN.authorizedTimeout);
    // Send request to determine whether the user is authorized
    $.ajax({
        url: "//ajax.example.net/authorized",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data.authorized){
                // If the user is authorized then check again in timeout milliseconds
                MN.authorizedTimeout = setTimeout(MN.isUserAuthorized,data.timeout_milliseconds);
                // Set authorized to true
                authorized = true;
            }else{
                // If the session has expired then proceed to informing the user
                MN.userSessionExpired();
                // Set authorized to false
                authorized = false;
            }
        }
    });
    // Return the session status boolean
    return authorized;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

Nevertheless I'd consider it as a better practice to calculate the online status serverside. So you can make sure that there's no inconsistency with the time. You only have your servertime.

For getting the online status you can go for a long polling approach. I've made you an example:

```
(function checkLoginStatus(){
    $.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'loginstatus.php',
      data: {userid : 25},
      success: function(data){
        if(data.logged_in !== true){
          //Log the user out
        }
      }, 
      dataType: "json", 
      complete: checkLoginStatus, 
      timeout: 15000 
    });
})();
```

This will make sure that a new request is made only when 15 seconds passed and when the request is complete.

**Old Answer:**

If your only concern is to watch over logged in users you don't need to poll. I'd keep the whole thing serverside. Just add a "last_active" field to your users table.

Whenever a user interacts (visits another site) update the timestamp to the current timestamp.

To detect whether a user is online take the current timestamp and subtract the "last_active" timestamp from it. If the difference is bigger than one hour, you know your user is inactive.

That's how I usually handle it. It also more efficient (regarding ressources) than doing it 
with AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not really what I am looking for. I have an auditing table to tell me when the user was last active. What I am trying to do is log a user out if their session expires. The only way to know whether their session has expired is by looking at the database and seeing when they were last active... Therefore I have to have some sort of AJAX request

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. Just to be clear, I am handling all of my users sessions server side. Nothing needs to be passed to the authorized page to indicate who is logged in or anything. This pages simply gives a JSON object of the logged in users status. This is generated server side... The inconsistency with the time is exactly why I have asked this question, I would like to find a better way to immediately know when a users session has expired. Consider this, user opens a page A, he then opens another page B in a different tab. On page B, he clicks the logout button ***(continued)***

Comment: After clicking the logout button, he is obviously logged out but Page A does not reflect this. If he was to try and save one of the forms or so anything on the page, he would receive an error. Effectively, what I would like is a system that knows as soon as the users session has ended, this can be down to many reasons whether it has expired or he has logged out manually. I simply want to redirect the user as soon as the session has ended. The only way to know if the session has ended is by looking server side, thus, Short Polling, Long Polling, or websockets...???

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like in the big picture you would like something on the server that will alert the frontend at the moment a user's session expires.

Long-polling could do this. Basically you would have a backend controller that accepts connections and holds onto them until it gets a signal to send a response, or the connection times out. So your frontend would have a loop that basically sends a request and waits for a response. If the response comes back empty, it was a timeout, so send a new request. If the response has content, it wasn't a timeout, so you can take action. This achieves your goal, and many such systems are built this way. However, it is kind of a hack to use HTTP in reverse, and doesn't make for clean code.

A websocket is a bi-directional interface between a client and server. Here's what your client-side js would look like.

```
  function connect(){
    websocket = new WebSocket("wss://yoursite.com:8080");
    //attach event handlers
    websocket.onmessage = onMessage;
  }
  function onMessage(evt){
    // do your thing
  }
```

Once you call `connect()`, you can rest assured that `onMessage()` will take care of you when the server needs to reach the client. To me, sending messages from server to client is exactly why we have websockets, so they are the right tool for the job.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for your answer. From what I have found with websockets, they are not very simple on installing on Windows. Are you aware of any good tutorials, or could you guide me through. Most of my servers are Linux, but this particular projects runs off an MSSQL Database therefore it has to be Windows :-(

Comment: Are you using any web framework? There are some windows solutions listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websocket

Comment: Nope, afraid not. I use my own framework... Which do you recommend? Ratchet? I have done so much research in the past about web sockets but there is so little info on the web about actually how to use them and how they work... It is nice to finally find someone who knows what they are talking about! Thank you for your time thus far! :-)

Comment: I am using Ratchet, but that is on a LAMP server where I am heavily leveraging Symfony as a web framework. If you don't have and don't need a web framework, I would go for something more lightweight. Have you looked into node.js? This seems to be a very popular choice. Here's a tutorial for setting up an echo server on Windows 7: http://cjihrig.com/blog/websockets-in-node-js-0-8-6-for-windows-7/